# Why does my Handlebars not have a compile method?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

I am setting up a `Backbone` project with `Handlebars` and I am having an issue with `Handlebars` not finding the compile method.  Here is my config file:

```
require.config({
  hbs: {
    templateExtension: '.hbs'
  },
  paths: {
    backbone: "libs/backbone/backbone",
    handlebars: 'libs/handlebars/handlebars.amd',
    hbs: 'libs/requirejs-hbs/hbs',
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
    jqueryMockAjax: 'libs/jquery-mockjax/jquery.mockjax',
    text: 'libs/requirejs-text/text',
    templates: 'templates/',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore'
  },
  shim: {
    backbone: {
      deps: [
        'underscore',
        'jquery'
      ],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    hbs: {
      deps: ['handlebars'],
      exports: 'hbs'
    },
    jqueryMockAjax: {
      deps: [ 'jquery' ],
      exports: '$.mockjax'
    },
    underscore: {
      exports: '_'
    }
  }
});

require(['app'], function(App) {
  'use strict';

  var app = new App();
  app.render();
});
```

Here is the `app.js` that I am trying to render:

```
define(function(require) {

  var Backbone = require('backbone');
  var testTemplate = require('hbs!templates/test');

  var router = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),
    template: testTemplate,
    render: function() {
      return $(this.el).html(this.template());
    }
  });

  return router;
});
```

When `Handlebars` calls the `hbs.js` file on line 25 it cannot find the `compile` function

```
define(["handlebars"], function(Handlebars) {
  var buildMap = {},
      templateExtension = ".hbs";

  return {

    // http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html#apiload
    load: function (name, parentRequire, onload, config) {

      // Get the template extension.
      var ext = (config.hbs && config.hbs.templateExtension ? config.hbs.templateExtension : templateExtension);

      if (config.isBuild) {
        // Use node.js file system module to load the template.
        // Sorry, no Rhino support.
        var fs = nodeRequire("fs");
        var fsPath = config.dirBaseUrl + "/" + name + ext;
        buildMap[name] = fs.readFileSync(fsPath).toString();
        onload();
      } else {
        // In browsers use the text-plugin to the load template. This way we
        // don't have to deal with ajax stuff
        parentRequire(["text!" + name + ext], function(raw) {
          // Just return the compiled template
 ****HERE onload(Handlebars.compile(raw));
        });
      }

    },

    // http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html#apiwrite
    write: function (pluginName, name, write) {
      var compiled = Handlebars.precompile(buildMap[name]);
      // Write out precompiled version of the template function as AMD
      // definition.
      write(
        "define('hbs!" + name + "', ['handlebars'], function(Handlebars){ \n" +
          "return Handlebars.template(" + compiled.toString() + ");\n" +
        "});\n"
      );
    }

  };
});
```

The `Handlebars` variable gives me the Handlebars environment, but it has an extra layer in it, so I have to change that line to `Handlebars.default.compile(raw)`.  Where is that `default` object coming from and how do I get rid of it?  I wouldn't worry about it, but if I pull down this project somewhere else I am always going to have to remember to do that.

Comment: What version are you using? Check [here](http://handlebarsjs.com/) and download the latest version `1.1.2`.

Comment: I am using version `1.1.2`.  All of my dependencies were pulled in by `bower` and getting the `latest`.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue right now

Comment: I did not figure this out question out specifically, so I used the `hbs.js` plugin.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905412/requirejs-is-not-loading-my-handlebars-dependencies-like-i-expect) is a question that I asked today and everything  works perfectly now.  Here is my [gruntfile](https://github.com/mjhamm75/gruntfile) that I am using where I have all of this working.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is how I fixed this issue, although I do not understand completely why the configuration above did not work.  The `hbs` plugin had a folder with all the dependencies it needed in it, like `handlebars`.  When I referred to the `handlebars` copy contained in the `hbs` directory, then everything worked like it was supposed to.  I do not understand why the vanilla copy of `handlebars` did not work.  I was not using the `handlebars` runtime, it was the full version, but still there was an issue.  After I resolved this, then my template stuff just worked.

Answer (score 63):

I just encountered this myself, using Handlebars for this first time.  It's likely that you're using the "runtime" build of Handlebars.  I included this one in my requirements, mistakenly assuming it was the minified version or something.

But in fact the runtime version is significantly smaller as it excludes the template compiler, and is for use only with pre-compiled templates.  If you're compiling the template client-side then you need the full version from http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v3.0.3.js  (Note: This link may be out of date; you're probably better off going directly to handlebarsjs.com and looking for the current download for the "full version", as opposed to runtime.)

Otherwise, you can follow the instructions on the Handlebars website to run the template compiler.  You need node for this.  The template compiler produces a JavaScript file containing the pre-compiled template code which you need to link to your page along with the Handlebars runtime build.

Comment: 16 upvotes (just ran into this myself). Maybe they should consider a more informative comment on the link in their site.

Comment: As a followup to this, it should be noted that my link to the full version of Handlebars is surely out of date by now; please visit the Handlebars website to find the latest version.