# Requirejs is not loading my handlebars dependencies like I expect

Tags: javascript, requirejs, handlebars.js

I am trying to load some js files with require.  Here is my config file:

```
define(function() {

  "use strict";

  require.config({
    hbs : {
      templateExtension : 'hbs',
      disableHelpers: true,
      disableI18n : true
    },

    shim: {
      'underscore': {
        exports: '_'
      },
      'backbone': {
        deps: [
          'underscore',
          'jquery'
        ],
        exports: 'Backbone'
      },
      json2 : {
        exports: "JSON"
      },
      'jqueryMockAjax': {
        exports: '$.mockjax',
        deps: ['jquery']
      }
    },

    paths: {

      jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
      jqueryMockAjax: 'libs/jquery-mockjax/jquery.mockjax',
      underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore',
      backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone',

      handlebars : 'libs/hbs/handlebars',
      text: 'libs/text/text',
      hbs: 'libs/hbs/hbs',
      i18nprecompile : 'libs/i18nprecompile',
      json2 : 'libs/json2/json2'
    }
  });
});
```

As you can see my js vendor files are located in my `libs` directory.  My directory structure looks like this:

```
+project
  +app
    +js
      +libs
    app.js
    main.js
```

Most of my dependencies are loading like they should, like `jquery` and `underscore`, but the handlebars stuff is not loading like it should.  For example, I have a path to `handlebars.js` as `libs/handlebars/handlebars` and it is removing the `libs` part of the path.  With other files it is not.  Here is my network tab showing what gets pulled in and what doesnt.

[image]

You can see the `libs` part of the path being removed.  I dont know what that means.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding handlebars to your shim configuration because it is not AMD complient, same with json2 and i18np...

Answer (score 0):

The reason that I was having import issues, was that when `bower` pulled in the `hbs` plugin, it pulled in all of the files that I needed for that plugin to work.  `handlebars`, `i18nprecompile` and `json2` were all in a directory in the `hbs` plugin.  When I referred to the copies in that file, then everything worked just like it was supposed to work.  I don't understand why the previously defined paths did not work.  If anybody has some info on that issue please comment.